# Stripe Error "Invalid API Key" after deploying to Netlify

Tags: stripe-payments, netlify

I have implemented Stripe through Firebase's "Run Payments with Stripe" extension. On my local machine it works as supposed, but after I've deployed it to Netlify I am getting this error:

[image]

[image]

Here is JS code:

```
export const handleCheckOut = async (uid) => {
    const checkOutRef = await doc(collection(database, 'users', uid, 'checkout_sessions'));
    onSnapshot(checkOutRef, async (snap) => {
        const { error, sessionId } = snap.data()

        if(error) {
            alert("An error occurred:", error.message)
        }
        if(sessionId) {
            const STRIPE_KEY = `${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}`;
            const stripe = await loadStripe(STRIPE_KEY)
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId})
        }
    })
}
```

I am building a website for my portfolio, so I am using a test mode keys. Public key (REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY) is added to Netlify's environmental variables and restricted key is added to Firebase extension's configurations.
What can be the issue here?

Comment: Are you able to successful log out your `REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY` environment variable? Is it the value you expect?

Comment: @JonathanSteele I was while it was on my local machine, not sure how I can do it to a deployed website

Comment: please check payload are you sending api key?

Comment: You'd add the same logs to your `handleCheckOut` function, and then check the browser console output for the `console.log` when the `handleCheckOut` function is invoked.

Comment: @VipulRam here are payload values: key: undefined, eid: NA, browser_locale: en-US, redirect_type: stripe_js

Comment: @rey2197 please make sure that value in key is not undefined. Instead of using env variable use direct value and try